# Image rotation with mouse instance - tkinter

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a program in which an image can be moved and rotated on a canvas. Regarding "Rotate_img", I have had some problems because in some cases the quality of the image is lost and in other cases it only shows a section of the image rotated.
I would like to make a function in which the image can rotate 90 ° clockwise each time I right click.

```
def import_img(self):
    self.evaporator = PhotoImage(file="E_evaporation.png")
    #self.window_mo is a Canvas. It was created in other function.
    self.window_mo.create_image(15, 25, image=self.evaporator, anchor="nw", tags="movil")

    self.window_mo.tag_bind("movil", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.Selection_img)
    self.window_mo.tag_bind("movil", "<Button1-Motion>", self.Move_img)
    self.window_mo.tag_bind("movil", "<ButtonPress-3>", self.Rotate_img)

    self.img_selected = None

def Selection_img(self,event):
    pict = self.window_mo.find_withtag(CURRENT)
    self.img_selected = (pict,event.x,event.y)

def Move_img(self,event):
    x,y = event.x,event.y
    pict,x1,y1 = self.img_selected
    self.window_mo.move(pict,x-x1,y-y1)
    self.img_selected = (pict,x,y)

def Rotate_img(self,event):
    pass
```

Currently with this section of code I can move a selected image. Could you help me with the "Rotate_img" function?

Sorry for my english.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try [Image.rotate()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate) from `Pillow` module.

Comment: This method doesn't function when I want to select an image that is on a canvas to rotate. I want to select an image and rotate it.

Comment: You need to change to use `Image` and `ImageTk.PhotoImage` classes instead of tkinter `PhotoImage` class.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! An observation. When I rotate the image only one section appears. Can I do something to make the image look complete?

Comment: I did it. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html